# c++ realloc same pointer warranty

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation, realloc

Using the std::realloc function:

If the new size is smaller, does it always have warranty to keep the memory block on the same position and only make it smaller, or it can move sometimes the whole block?

The reason to ask this, is that we'are writing a large and very hard code, and it is useful to make read only all the variables we need to leave unchanged, to obtain compiler's errors, when we try to change the wrong variable.

```
#include<cstdlib>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
  //From 10,000,000 unsigned ints to 10 unsigned ints
  unsigned int * const array=new unsigned int[10000000];
  cout<<array<<endl;
  realloc(array,10*sizeof(unsigned int));
  cout<<array<<endl;
  delete array;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't mix `new()` and `realloc()`.

Comment: You can't realloc memory that was allocated with `new`.

Comment: Which C library are you using? (realloc coming from the C library)

Comment: You can't mix `new` with `realloc`.  So instead of this question and this one from you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25898160/c-make-dynamic-array-smaller, write your own version of `realloc` that respects operator `new`.  Then you won't have any questions because you would control exactly how your home-made `realloc` function behaves.

Comment: `realloc` might move the allocated chunk of memory, even if it shrinks, to improve future allocations. For example, large allocations might come from one region of memory and small allocations from another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although I agree with the other answers in that you should not depend on it, there is an answer to be found in the `glibc` source. (I am assuming that you are using `glibc`, as you have not (yet) answered my comment asking which C library you are using)

**EDIT: Using `realloc` on memory allocated by `new` is indeed disallowed, as other answers have mentioned.**

## Memory allocated without internally using `mmap`

If a block of memory is not allocated with `mmap`, [__libc_realloc](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=malloc/malloc.c;h=6cbe9f32f8929a03796f8bd859a2450e207ebbde;hb=HEAD#l2951) calls the [_int_realloc](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=malloc/malloc.c;h=6cbe9f32f8929a03796f8bd859a2450e207ebbde;hb=HEAD#l4187) function, which contains the following snippet of code:

```
if ((unsigned long) (oldsize) >= (unsigned long) (nb))
 {
   /* already big enough; split below */
   newp = oldp;
   newsize = oldsize;
 }
```

This makes the pointer to the new memory equal the pointer to the old memory and sets the size accordingly. Note the `split below` comment; the old memory block may be resized to the requested size, but is not moved.

---

## Memory allocated internally using `mmap`

If the memory was internally allocated using `mmap`, there are two ways of resizing the memory area; `mremap_chunk` or a series of calls to `malloc`, `memcpy` and `free`. If the `mremap_chunk` function is available, it is used instead of the latter option.

### Memory reallocated using `mremap_chunk`

The function [mremap_chunk](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=malloc/malloc.c;h=6cbe9f32f8929a03796f8bd859a2450e207ebbde;hb=HEAD#l2833) contains this snippet of code

```
/* No need to remap if the number of pages does not change.  */
if (size + offset == new_size)
    return p;
```

If the number of pages does not change from the old size to the new size, there is no need to remap and the old pointer is returned.

### Memory reallocated using `malloc`, `memcpy` and `free`

If `mremap_chunk` is not available, the [__libc_realloc](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=malloc/malloc.c;h=6cbe9f32f8929a03796f8bd859a2450e207ebbde;hb=HEAD#l2951) source continues with the following:

```
/* Note the extra SIZE_SZ overhead. */
if (oldsize - SIZE_SZ >= nb)
    return oldmem;                         /* do nothing */
```

If the `oldsize` variable minus the chunk size is more than or equal to the new size, just return the old memory.

---

Well then, here we are. In all cases, glibc returns a pointer to the old memory, not moving it (but possibly resizing it). If you are using glibc (and can somehow guarantee that the only C library you are using it with is glibc, and can guarantee that it won't change at some point in the future), you are able to rely on the behavior that `realloc` does not move a block of memory if the requested size is equal to or less than the old size.

Comment: Very implementation-dependent and volatile information. Be aware that even if the returned pointer is actually the same as the passed pointer, all variables heretofore storing the old pointer are indeterminate afterwards. This is not a theoretical point, but was demonstrated in the wild, using clang, in a blog post I recently read on UB. I'm just sorry that I lost the link...

Comment: That seems weird- a shame you've lost the link, seems like an interesting read. But yes, I agree with you; this was more of an interest in how `glibc` handled this than very portable or practical information.

Comment: Your answer is very good. Thank you very much. I didn't understand very well this sentence: "EDIT: Using realloc on memory allocated by new is indeed disallowed, as other answers have mentioned." You are asking other users to edit what they wrote? Because it is possible to use realloc with new and delete?

Comment: Edit signifies that I edited the post later to include that information; I'm reiterating that using realloc with new and delete is not allowed.

Comment: That said, if you wanted to dive into the internals of g++, you might discover that mixing `new[]` and `realloc` like this "works" in the same way as what you've already talked about above works. That is to say, it's not guaranteed but maybe it does happen on one or more particular implementations just because of the "obvious" way to implement `new[]` for POD types.

Answer (score 3):

No!! If `realloc` succeeds, the old pointer (unless it was a nullpointer) is indeterminate.

Also, do not mix incompatible memory-management-functions (assume incompatibility unless guaranteed otherwise).

`realloc` only has the guarantees explicitly given in the standard:

- If return-value is non-0: New pointer points to of at least `size` byte, the first min(oldsize, newsize) being equal to the passed block.
- Else if `size` is non-0, nothing happened to the passed block.
- Else the old block may have been deallocated, or not.

Moral: Never pass a 0 size to `realloc`, and only use the old pointer for anything (including comparison to the new pointer), if `realloc` failed (or you passed a nullpointer).

> #### 7.22.3.5 The realloc function
>
> ```
> #include <stdlib.h>
> void *realloc(void *ptr, size_t size);
> ```
>
> 2 The `realloc` function deallocates the old object pointed to by `ptr` and returns a
>   pointer to a new object that has the size specified by `size`. The contents of the new
>   object shall be the same as that of the old object prior to deallocation, up to the lesser of
>   the new and old sizes. Any bytes in the new object beyond the size of the old object have
>   indeterminate values.
>   3 If `ptr` is a null pointer, the `realloc` function behaves like the `malloc` function for the
>   specified size. Otherwise, if `ptr` does not match a pointer earlier returned by a memory
>   management function, or if the space has been deallocated by a call to the `free` or
>   `realloc` function, the behavior is undefined. If memory for the new object cannot be
>   allocated, the old object is not deallocated and its value is unchanged.
>
> Returns
>   4 The `realloc` function returns a pointer to the new object (which may have the same
>   value as a pointer to the old object), or a null pointer if the new object could not be
>   allocated.

Comment: The OP is not passing 0 to realloc, so most of your answer is completely redundant in answering his question. Sound familiar?

Comment: Well, now you are reaching. I'm giving the complete picture, which is somewhat different from decrying his example for illustrating his question.

Comment: Pointing out the adverse effects (memory leak, accessing deallocated memory) of using a function incorrectly is not "decrying his example", it is attempting to illustrate why he should not use the method he is trying to use. Get a grip.

Comment: Well, my last try to make you see the point (or as you put it, to let you "get a grip"): His example illustrates his question whether he can assume the new pointer being identical to the old pointer by assuming so, and you don't see that saying No to the question is identical to saying that the assumption the example is built on does not hold? Some people...

Comment: My last try for you: He said "can I do X?". I replied "No you can't do X, because here's what will go wrong if you do". You replied "no you can't do Y". As you said, some people.

Answer (score 2):

[C99](http://people.freebsd.org/~green/c9x-draft.txt) draft 7.20.3.4 says:

> [#4] The realloc function  returns  a  pointer  to  the  new 
>              object  (which  **may  have the same value as a pointer to the 
>              old object**), or a null pointer if the new object  could  not 
>              be allocated.

You should not assume it.

And also: don't mix `new` and `realloc` as πάντα already wrote in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing's guaranteed about `realloc`. It might shrink the block in place, or it might allocate a new one and copy the data. It might also fail.

An important point: `realloc` is only for reallocating memory that was previously allocated by `malloc`. In your code above, you are using `new` which has no equivalent for reallocation.

Also `realloc` actually *returns* the address of the new memory block, so in your code above you will be a) leaking this and b) referencing/freeing potentially already de-allocated memory.

Comment: As he said, he wants to know if it'S safe (which it isn't).

Comment: If there was a guarantee that `realloc` always returns the same pointer if the passed block is at least `size` bytes big, not saving the returned pointer because you know you are only shrinking the block anyway would be a valid choice. Thus the last paragraph is completely redundant with answering his question.

Comment: @Deduplicator: The very first thing I said was "nothing's guaranteed about realloc". Perhaps you need to improve your reading comprehension?

Comment: Ok, I'll try to rephrase that for you: He's providing code to illustrate his question, which is whether he can assume the pointer `realloc` returned is the pointer he passed, considering that he asks for shrinking (or at least not enlarging) the block. Your answer is: No, realloc does not provide that guarantee, and btw your example has a bug because realloc does not guarantee the block won't move. Do you now see how that last paragraph is at best completely redundant?

Comment: @Deduplicator: No, because he's using the function incorrectly. How is pointing this out redundant?